# Isomorphism type of order 16 subgroup of $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

[This question is prompted by Robinson ex. 1.6.17 which I am self-studying.
The question is mostly about improving my style and rigour.]

I needed to find the isomorphism type of a Sylow 2 subgroup of $S_6$.

Obviously such a subgroup is of order 16 (the highest power of 2 dividing 6!)
Since all the Sylow 2 subgroups are isomorphic, I just need to pin one down, call it $S$, and investigate it.

First I looked at the representation of $S_6$ as permutations, and spotted that (some) permutations on elements 1..6 elements can be split into a direct sum of permutations on 1..4 and 5..6.  So $S_4 \times S_2$ is a subgroup of $S_6$.

Question: how to make the previous remark more rigorous/elegant?

By Sylow again, $S_4$ has a subgroup of order $8$. So there is a subgroup of order 16 within $S_4 \times S_2$.

Again, looking at $S_4$ as symmetries of 1,2,3,4 and playing around I eventually found elements $a = (1 2)$ and $b = (1 4 2 3)$ with $abab=1$, I realised that $a$ and $b$ generate $D_8$, and so $S \cong D_8\times Z_2$.

Question: how to remove some of the guesswork from this step.  For example, I know $D_8$ is a candidate of the right order, how can I show that it is or isn't the right group more easily than guessing permutations?  [I can usually understand the general theories, but when confronted by specific groups I go to pieces and end up tabulating.]

Thanks.

Comment: A remark to help you improve your mathematical lexicon: in the given context the syntagm does nevertheless get the idea across, but there is no such thing as a "direct sum of permutations". Also, $\Sigma_6$ is by definition the group of all permutations of the natural interval $[1, 6]$, so it is somewhat awkward to speak of the representation of this group by permutations of $[1, 6]$ (formally, this would be the identity representation). There is no need to represent an object by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the remark that $S_6$ contains a subgroup ismorphic to $S_4\times S_2$, I believe the neatest way of saying it is that the standard embedding of $S_4$ in $S_6$ (i.e. permutations fixing 5 and 6) commutes elementwise with $H=\langle (56)\rangle\simeq S_2$ and their intersection is trivial, so that their product $S_4\cdot H=\{\sigma\tau\ |\ \sigma\in S_4, \tau\in H\}$ is indeed isomorphic to their direct product.

The rest of the argument is fine in itself: moreover, you will have to do some handiwork when dealing with concrete groups. For example, knowing that $D_8$ has the right order is not enough.  Even if you exclude abelian groups of order 8 (which seem unlikely to be 2-Sylows of $S_4$), you are left with two options, namely $D_8$ or $Q_8$ (quaternions), and it is concrete exploration of $S_4$ to give you the answer on which of the two is the correct Sylow group.

Surely, though, there are ways to pick the right permutations that are more clever than others: in this case, moreover, there is a way you can get (somewhat) naturally to the answer, i.e. costruct a $2$-Sylow of $S_n$ inductively on $n$. For a positive integer $n$, call $\mu_2(n)$ the exponent of 2 in the prime factorization of $n!$, $P_n$ the (isomorphism class) of a 2-Sylow of $S_n$.
Clearly, $P_2\simeq C_2$ (where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$), and this holds for $P_3$ as well since $S_2$ embeds in $S_3$ and $\mu_2(3)=\mu_2(2)$.
As $\mu_2(4)=\mu_2(2)+2$, you must enlarge $\langle(12)\rangle<S_4$ by a factor 4. One factor 2 comes naturally by embedding $S_2$ in $S_4$ as $\langle(34)\rangle$: for the same argument used in the first paragraph, you may clearly see that $$H=\langle(12)\rangle\cdot\langle(34)\rangle\simeq C_2\times C_2.$$ Now, you have no more disjoint $C_2$ to multiply to your $H$, but you can still *exchange* $(12)$ and $(34)$, namely by conjugating by the double transposition $(13)(24)$. If $K=\langle(13)(24)\rangle$, this gives the product $HK$ (which is a subgroup, since $H$ and $K$ commute) a natural structure of semidirect product $H\rtimes K$ or, if you prefer, the isomorphism structure of $D_8$, so that $P_4\simeq (C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_2$.
At this point, since $\mu_2(6)=\mu_2(4)+1$, just multiplying $P_4<S_6$ by the disjoint $C_2$ given by $\langle (56)\rangle$ does the trick, and leaves you with $P_6\simeq P_4\times P_2$.

Also, this construction has the advantage of showing a pattern. In fact, if you compute $\mu_2(n)$, you will easily see that:

1. $P_{2^{n+1}}\simeq (P_{2^{n}}\times P_{2^{n}})\rtimes C_2$ as in the case of $P_4$, which is normally written $P_{2^{n}}\wr C_2$ and called a *wreath product*;
2. if $n=a_0+a_1\cdot 2+\cdots+a_k\cdot 2^k$ in base 2, $P_n\simeq \prod_{j=1}^k (P_{2^i})^{a_i}$, as with $P_6$;
3. this generalizes to other primes in the obvious way.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer!  I'm aware of both semidirect products and wreath products, though not yet confident to apply them to real examples, so this is very helpful.  Just to clarify, are you setting K = <(13)(24)>?  Is there a normality condition to check (for the semidirect product,) or is that automatic by the construction?

Comment: Precisely, it slipped my mind to define $K$. Yes, I was not a hundred percent precise about the semidirect product: in fact, one has to declare *which* semidirect product it is, i.e. what is the morphism $K\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ defining the product. In this case, though, as I tried to quickly hint about, the "natural" morphism is conjugation by elements of $K$. Indeed, as you noticed, this works precisely because $K$ normalizes $H$: but this comes at once from the choice of $K$, since $(13)(24)$ acts on $H$ by conjugation switching its generators, so clearly sends $H$ to itself.